# Install VS.NET Extension from Command Line

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

Is there any way to install a VS.NET extension from the command line?  I'm working on setting up development VMs using vagrant and powershell for provisioning, and would like to be able to automate the installation of some of my favorite extensions as well.

Comment: What kind of VS.NET exstension?  There's no way to know if it can be installed via command-line if you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: I was hoping to just automate what gets done in Tools >> Extensions and Updates, where it searches Visual Studio Gallery online and automatically installs them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use VSIXInstaller to automate extension installation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sergey's answer is correct, but here's the powershell script I used to automate it (stolen from a chocolatey package I found):

```
function Get-Batchfile ($file) {
  $cmd = "`"$file`" & set"
    cmd /c $cmd | Foreach-Object {
      $p, $v = $_.split('=')
        Set-Item -path env:$p -value $v
    }
}

function VsVars32()
{
    $BatchFile = join-path $env:VS120COMNTOOLS "vsvars32.bat"
    Get-Batchfile `"$BatchFile`"
}

function curlex($url, $filename) {
  $path = [io.path]::gettemppath() + "\" + $filename
  if( test-path $path ) { rm -force $path }
  (new-object net.webclient).DownloadFile($url, $path)

  return new-object io.fileinfo $path
}

function installsilently($url, $name) {
  echo "Installing $name"
  $extension = (curlex $url $name).FullName
  $result = Start-Process -FilePath "VSIXInstaller.exe" -ArgumentList "/q $extension" -Wait -PassThru;
}


# INSTALL VS Extenaions
installsilently http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329/file/6390/49/VsVim.vsix VsVim.vsix
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this [batch-install-vsix](https://chocolatey.org/packages/batch-install-vsix) chocolatey package to configure and install extensions.

Comment: Batch-Install-Vsix looks pefect for what I need but how exactly to you get the full URL to the vsix file? I can't find out how to get that URL from the visual studio market place. Did you manually compose the link given a convention? Thanks!